# Merge object from different array with identical key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I merge this array of object

```
[
    {
        substoreUuid: '1450215d-e1a4-454d-8042-014d0f70f01e',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169'
    }
]
```

to this array of object where the key name is the same

```
[
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169',
        quantity: 2,
        uuid: '799898cc-f74a-42d9-9fa2-84da238d6b39'
    },
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: 'a0e64311-2410-48be-b97d-17c68a0ad2a1',
        quantity: 1,
        uuid: '211c626c-e8f7-40d7-b42a-690e2fa0082b'
    }
]
```

as you can see, I need to merge the object from two different array.

expected output:

```
[
    {
        substoreUuid: '1450215d-e1a4-454d-8042-014d0f70f01e', 
        quantity: 2, 
        uuid: '799898cc-f74a-42d9-9fa2-84da238d6b39',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169',
    }
]
```

here is what I have so far

```
const substoreArr = [
    {
        substoreUuid: '1450215d-e1a4-454d-8042-014d0f70f01e',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169'
    }
];

const distributionStore = [
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169',
        quantity: 2,
        uuid: '799898cc-f74a-42d9-9fa2-84da238d6b39'
    },
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: 'a0e64311-2410-48be-b97d-17c68a0ad2a1',
        quantity: 1,
        uuid: '211c626c-e8f7-40d7-b42a-690e2fa0082b'
     }
];

const newArr = distributionStore.map(diststore => {
   for (const sub of substoreArr) {
     if (sub.store_uuid === diststore.storeUuid) {
        return diststore;
     }
   }
}); //output [undefined, undefined]
```

The output will remove non-related `storeUuid` and strip away a few key also. How do I merge it in vanilla js and the faster way.

Comment: What does "merge" mean?  Which properties do you copy over?  What happens if both objects both have a property with conflicting values.  You need to more fully describe what the rules are for merging.

Comment: Which part of this problem do you not understand?  Surely, you can iterate through an array and find an object with a given property, right?  You really ought to make an attempt to solve this yourself and then, if you get stuck, you can post the code you already have and then ask a specific question about it.  We aren't meant to be a coding service. when you've written no code yourself yet.

Comment: i have updated my question. I have two differect array of object and I need to merge it based on the same key which in this case is `storeUuid`

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I took the liberty of reformatting your array/object literals into a more consistent and explicitly nested format. This helps make it easier for someone who is reading and mentally parsing your data structure.

Comment: you're welcome sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I learn so far. I use `reduce` to map to the same key

```js
const substoreArr = [{substoreUuid: '1450215d-e1a4-454d-8042-014d0f70f01e',
    storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169'}]
const distributionStore = [{acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
    storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169',
    quantity: 2,
    uuid: '799898cc-f74a-42d9-9fa2-84da238d6b39' },
  { acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
    storeUuid: 'a0e64311-2410-48be-b97d-17c68a0ad2a1',
    quantity: 1,
    uuid: '211c626c-e8f7-40d7-b42a-690e2fa0082b' } ]

const result = [substoreArr, distributionStore].reduce((a, b) => {
  return a.map((c, i) => {
    const {acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid, storeUuid: sUuid, ...attrs} = b[i];
    const {storeUuid, ...attr} = c;
    return Object.assign({}, attr, attrs)
  })
});
console.log(result)
```

any improvement is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I've made working solution to your problem. You should probably refactor this code and split operations to separate functions.

```
 const result = substoreArr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const filtered = distributionStore
        .filter(e => e.storeUuid === val.storeUuid)
        .map(e => ({...e, ...val}));

    if (filtered.length > 0) {
        return [...acc, ...filtered];
    } else {
        return acc;
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter the result by `storeUuid`, then map the result, get only required properties. All code are vanilla Javascript ES6.

```js
const substoreArr = [
    {
        substoreUuid: '1450215d-e1a4-454d-8042-014d0f70f01e',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169'
    }
];

const distributionStore = [
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169',
        quantity: 2,
        uuid: '799898cc-f74a-42d9-9fa2-84da238d6b39'
    },
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: 'a0e64311-2410-48be-b97d-17c68a0ad2a1',
        quantity: 1,
        uuid: '211c626c-e8f7-40d7-b42a-690e2fa0082b'
     }
];

const newArr = distributionStore
  .filter(x => substoreArr.find(i => i.storeUuid === x.storeUuid))
  .map(({ storeUuid, quantity, uuid }) => ({ storeUuid, quantity, uuid, ...substoreArr.find(i => i.storeUuid === storeUuid) }));

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution can be achieved by building a lookup of substores by storeUuid as the key, to avoid the nested loop.

Having a nested loop means you have to compare each item in the first array, with each item in the second array, which will take time proportional to `n1 * n2`. But if you build the hashmap of substore first, you end up doing 2 separate loops so the time taken is proportional to `n1 + n1` which will be much faster for larger arrays.

```js
const substoreArr = [
    {
        substoreUuid: '1450215d-e1a4-454d-8042-014d0f70f01e',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169'
    }
];

const distributionStore = [
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: '6627a93e-1e16-4e08-9057-44ce701ba169',
        quantity: 2,
        uuid: '799898cc-f74a-42d9-9fa2-84da238d6b39'
    },
    {
        acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid: '080d7831-9cab-4bf4-af92-bae7b75bd50d',
        storeUuid: 'a0e64311-2410-48be-b97d-17c68a0ad2a1',
        quantity: 1,
        uuid: '211c626c-e8f7-40d7-b42a-690e2fa0082b'
     }
];

// build an object (or hash) for substores, where the key is the storeUuid for fast lookup
const substoresByStoreUuid = {}

substoreArr.forEach(substore => 
  substoresByStoreUuid[substore.storeUuid]=substore
)


const result = distributionStore
  // remove items that don't have a matching substore
  .filter(store => substoresByStoreUuid[store.storeUuid])
  // return the merged properties
  .map(({quantity, uuid, storeUuid}) => ({ 
    quantity, 
    uuid, 
    storeUuid, 
    substoreUuid: substoresByStoreUuid[storeUuid].substoreUuid
  }))
```